# Is !document.cookie reliable?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm wondering if using the following Javascript code is reliable:

```
if (!document.cookie) {
    alert('Cookies are disabled.');
}
```

I've tested this in IE, Firefox and Chrome and it seems that when you disabled cookies, the document.cookie object becomes unavailable. Does anyone have any experience with this method working/not working?

Many Thanks
Stephen

**Additional**

I'm well aware that this method requires JavaScript to be enabled on the client. I'm also aware of other server-side/JavaScript solutions. Please can the discussion remain on topic.

Comment: It may be as unreliable - but you may combine `document.cookie` tests with `navigator.cookieEnabled`.

Comment: I don't know. The question, as worded, sounds very reliable. When you evaluate document.cookie (or !document.cooke) does it return the correct value all the time? Yes.

Is it an indicator of whether or not the cookies sub-system is fully  active? Not really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reliable way to me in this scenario (check if cookies are **disabled**, you don't mind about the javascript issues, and need a client-side solution) is to use a set function for a test cookie, then a get function to read it back. If the test cookie can't be read back, cookies are off.

You can write your own implementation of it reading a great resource from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), use a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) or an [out-of-box solution](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_check_cookies.php).

Answer (score 10):

In XHTML documents, there is no `document.cookie` at all (up to Firefox 2 or forever on if you send the document as `application/xml`). I had to learn painfully, that it can be set on `document`, however:

```
document.cookie = "foo";
```

This is valid JS, and the browser shrugs its shoulders and sets the property `cookie` of the variable `document`. But the special magic to transform this in an HTTP header doesn't get called.

To put it in a nutshell: No, you can't be sure, that the absence of `document.cookie` is always identical with disabled cookies, and vice versa.

Comment: Obviously, it also relies on JavaScript being turned on. The user could have left cookies turned on, but turned off JavaScript.

Comment: @Paul: The question implies JS is on, or not? Otherwise the code is also not reliable if the client computer is turned off.

Comment: I didn’t read that implication from the question. It asked if using the JavaScript code in question was “reliable”. JavaScript being on is a secondary concern, but that’s why I added this point as a comment to what I thought was the best answer, and put the word “Obviously” at the start. (If the client computer is turned off, it doesn’t matter whether cookies are enabled or not. If JavaScript is turned off, presumably it still does.)

Comment: I don't see this behaviour on my XHTML page. I tried |javascript:alert(document.cookie);| and |javascript:alert(document.cookie = 'foo=bar');| in Firefox 3.0 and later. No problems at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @janmoesen: Seems they have fixed this one on XHTML documents (to prove that I wasn't phantasizing: http://simonwillison.net/2003/Jul/3/accessingCookies/ ). It was there in FF2. However, it stays valid, because you can also serve documents as `application/xml` (perhaps together with some in-browser XSLT or stuff) and then you have the same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a value on the server, and reading it on the client. If cookies are enabled, you should be able to read the same value. If not, they are disabled. Note that the site might have httpOnly enabled.

Comment: server side detection is the most reliable way

Answer (score 1):

Opera 7.10 will not understand document.cookie, so it is not reliable.
Try using this one instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false

//if not IE4+ nor NS6+
if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
document.cookie="testcookie"
cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false
}

//if (cookieEnabled) //if cookies are enabled on client's browser
//do whatever

</script>
```

It is compatible with most browsers and the ones which will not work with it are not used anymore. I have tested it with Internet Explorer 8.0, Firefox 3.6, Google Chrome 4.0, Opera 10.10 both within HTML and XHTML. While using HTML version with Internet Explorer 8.0 I had to confirm execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gotCookie = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

if(typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !gotCookie) {
    document.cookie = 'test';
    gotCookie       = (document.cookie.indexOf('test') != -1) ? true : false;
    }
```

if `gotCookie == true`, then you've `gotCookie` :)

note:
when there's no cookie set, `document.cookie` seems to be unavailable even if cookie is enabled in the browser. that's why we set it with `document.cookie = 'test'`, then check it on the next line. of course, assuming that js is enabled.