# Is document.cookie ever undefined?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm just curious if `document.cookie` can ever return `undefined`.

I read [quirksmode's article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) on cookies and I looked at "[Is !document.cookie reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288022/is-document-cookie-reliable)" but they don't explicitly answer this question.

Can `document.cookie` ever be `undefined`?

Comment: Some of my code that is pulling from cookies was breaking a page on my site. So I'm writing some defensive code and wasn't sure if I needed to account for `document.cookie` being undefined.

Comment: No, it's never `undefined` in browsers that support it, and that's almost every browser in use today. It's also not an ordinary object, but a very special one, with special properties, for instance you can set it's value multiple times without overwriting it.

Comment: that sounds like a problem with using an actual cookie that doesn't exist, not `document.cookie` itself

Comment: @CrayonViolent Yes but it got me thinking about this.

Comment: Old question, but this is kind of funny: ...No, it's never undefined in browsers that support it, and that's almost every browser in use today... - Well, if it's ALMOST all browsers, then it CAN be undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `document.cookie` property is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-8747038) in DOM Level 2, and implemented in [every major browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Browser_compatibility). It sets/gets a string, which may be an empty string (which is falsey, but not `undefined`).

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can read the spec here http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-8747038

It throws an error if it's set to a value that doesn't adhere to the spec.