# find a cookie exists in the cookie string - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need to find a cookie name is available or not in the cookie string , i have achieved this, we can use cookie-parser but i don't want to use the package so i have written the below code ,can i reduce the code in a  better way more optimised ?

```js
function checkCookie(cookie, cookieToBeSearched){
            if(cookie === "" || cookie === undefined){
                return false
            }
            let res = cookie.split(";").some(cookie => {
                let eachCookie = cookie.split("=");
                return eachCookie[0].trim() === cookieToBeSearched
            });
            return res;
        }

let cookie = "_ga=GA1.2.2091695351.1539084164; __qca=P0-338702612-1539084164095; __gads=ID=770d92bcdac8de40:T=1539084164:S=ALNI_MbsRKpoSJdn8tsdShMHMZUAR17uZA; _gid=GA1.2.798724103.1539582973";

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_gid"))

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_giddd"))
```

Comment: probably better to add to codereview 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is a nice solution.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var exp = new RegExp('[; ]'+name+'=([^\\s;]*)');
    var matchs = (' '+document.cookie).match(exp);
    if (matchs) return matchs[1];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: matchs is a string , you need to split it before returning it isn't ? when i checked it gives me an empty string

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS sorry it is a bug, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_name') > -1 ) {
  //alert("cookie exists");
   return true
}
```

Its simple!

Answer (score 0):

By converting the string as an object, we can use an Object/Hashmap to quickly find the corresponding value of key, rather than iterate over the array when we need to find the value of the key.

Therefore, we can leverage O(1) for `finding` in hashmap rather than O(N) by iterating over the array.

```
const cookies = (key, cookie = document.cookie) => {
  if (!cookie) return;
  return cookie.split(";").reduce((acc, item) => { 
    item ? acc[item.split('=')[0].trim()] = item.split('=')[1] : null;
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

cookies("key")
```

Comment: what about the cookie is empty or its undefined ?

Comment: it'll return undefined if the key is undefined, but if the value is empty  - the key will return the value is empty\

Comment: can you just try your code  it with instead of replacing document.cookie with either "" or undefined? "".split(";") or undefined.split(";") will throw an error isn't ?

Comment: ... but why would you replace document.cookie with undefined?, even if document.cookie has no length, the exmaple would not return an error.  if you want to ensure document.cookie is defined - 

you could use optional chaining...

Comment: [is document cookie ever undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673784/2312051)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid explicitly checking cookie value for `""` and `undefined`. You can also splitting the string on `=`.

```
function checkCookie(cookie, cookieToBeSearched){
        if(!cookie){
            return false
        }
        let res = cookie.split(";").some(cookie => {
            let cookieReg = new RegExp('^'+cookieToBeSearched+'=')
            return cookie.trim().match(cookieReg)
        });
        return Boolean(res);
    }

let cookie = "_ga=GA1.2.2091695351.1539084164; __qca=P0-338702612-1539084164095; __gads=ID=770d92bcdac8de40:T=1539084164:S=ALNI_MbsRKpoSJdn8tsdShMHMZUAR17uZA; _gid=GA1.2.798724103.1539582973";

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_gid"))

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_giddd"))
```